# How to expand vertically web's body when open menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm building a little vertically expandable menu in JQuery and I need some sort of help.

My main problem is that when I click on the menu to expand it, the web doesn't expand so I can't click the last menu's link because it's out of page. So I thought I need someway to expand the body of the document when the click happens, but I have no idea how this can be accomplished.

So, How can I expand the "canvas/body/etc..." vertically when open the menu?

And my second problem is: How can I do that the menu doesnt hide when click on link and changing from page?

Thanks!

My Jquery:

```
$(function() {
      var visibleFashion = false;

      $('#menu-fashion').css({'display':'none'});

      //FASHION
      $('#fbtn').click(function() {

        if (visibleFashion) {
          $('#menu-fashion').css({'display':'none'});
          visibleFashion = false;
          return;
        }

        $('#menu-fashion').css({'display':'block'});
        visibleFashion = true;


      });


      $('#menu-fashion').click(function() {
        $(this).css({'display':'none'});
        visibleFashion = false;
      });
});
```

And this is my section on HTML/PHP:

```
<!--Class menus-->
                <div id="fbtn" style="margin-top:10px; cursor:pointer;">Fashion</div>
                <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'container_id' => 'top-right-menu-fashion', 'fallback_cb' => false)); ?>
```

CSS:

```
#top-right-menu-fashion {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.menu-fashion{
        display: none;  
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot! Now its edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic of the thing you're trying to do is like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wssso8k/2/)**

```
$('#menu').height(0);

var menuOpen=false;
$('a').click(function(e){
    if(!menuOpen){
        $('#menu').animate({
            height:100
        },200);
        menuOpen=true;
    }
    else{
        $('#menu').animate({
            height:0
        },200);
        menuOpen=false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
$('section').not('a').click(function(e){
    if(menuOpen){
        $('#menu').animate({
            height:0
        },200);
        menuOpen=false;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

now you just have to insert this logic into your project and you're good to go.